# iPhone, cocos2d coordinate system

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, coordinate-systems

I've created CocosNode, then inserted sprite in this node. I moved node and sprite separately. As result node has some coordinate, sprite has another coordinate. I see sprite on the screen, but sprite's coordinates are out of the screen borders.

So could you please explain how can I convert sprite coordinates to screen coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: I found solution for that. I should do next: (node coordinate) - (sprite coordinate) I'll receive some value. If this value equals from 0 to 320, so it's visible in the screen.

If you have better solution, you are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Cocos provides methods for this.
To convert from your node's position to world space (cocos coord system, y increases toward the top of the screen) you would do:

```
[aSprite convertToWorldSpace:aSprite.position];
```

To convert from this coord system to iPhone view coord system (y increases toward the bottom of the screen) do:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[aSprite convertToWorldSpace:aSprite.position]];
```